# Okular is not displaying annotation stamp colors correctly

Tags: kde, okular

I just upgraded my Devuan Linux from ascii to beowulf.  Now my Okular annotations are not showing the stamps with the correct colors.  I have tried changing the colors, but there is no change. As seen in the screenshot example, it is difficult to read. I have transparency set to 50% which is usually very easy to read and the dark grey background is white.

Also, I just noticed that when I place the stamp, it has the correct coloring for a few tenths of a second then changes to this dark version. Also, gold bookmark stars are dark purple.

[image: how it looks]

Comment: Total guess, but maybe have a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/567886/okular-opens-pdfs-without-colours).

Comment: There was a suggestion on that link that said to try resetting defaults.  I thought I had done that by deleting the config files, but I guess not.  So I restored defaults via the menu and now the new stamps work the way the should.  Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind. It worked until I build my own custom buttons under `Configure Annotations`.

Comment: Just to clarify... I am still having the same problem.

Comment: Enough of this... I installed nixos package manager and installed the latest stable version of Okular and everything is bilss now...

Comment: Glad you found a solution. =)